# Why is 'this' refering to 'window' in this TypeScript snippet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Given this piece code:

```
module movieApp {
    export interface IHomeControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
        moviesToDownload: string[];
        active: string;

        deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie: any);

        markMovieAsDownloaded(movie: any);
    }

    export class HomeController {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope',
            '$location',
            'MovieService'
        ];

        constructor(private $scope: IHomeControllerScope, private $location: ng.ILocationService, private MovieService) {
            this.$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', (event) => {
                this.setActiveUrlPart();
            });

            MovieService.getMoviesToDownload().then(response => {
                this.$scope.moviesToDownload = response;
            });
        }

        private setActiveUrlPart() {
            var parts = this.$location.path().split('/');
            this.$scope.active = parts[1];
        }

        public get moviesToDownload() {
            return this.$scope.moviesToDownload;
        }

        public markMovieAsDownloaded(movie: any) {
            movie.Downloaded = true;
        }

        public deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie: any) {
            this.MovieService.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie).then(() => {
                debugger;
                this.$scope.moviesToDownload = _.without(this.$scope.moviesToDownload, movie);
            });
        }
    }
}

app.controller("HomeController", movieApp.HomeController);
```

Everything works just fine, but in the method `deleteMovieFromDownloadList` in the line `this.$scope.moviesToDownload = _.without(this.$scope.moviesToDownload, movie);`, `this` refers to the window object, instead of the actual object I expect.

The generated JavaScript looks like this:

```
var movieApp;
(function (movieApp) {
    var HomeController = (function () {
        function HomeController($scope, $location, MovieService) {
            var _this = this;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.$location = $location;
            this.MovieService = MovieService;
            this.$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
                _this.setActiveUrlPart();
            });

            MovieService.getMoviesToDownload().then(function (response) {
                _this.$scope.moviesToDownload = response;
            });
        }
        HomeController.prototype.setActiveUrlPart = function () {
            var parts = this.$location.path().split('/');
            this.$scope.active = parts[1];
        };

        Object.defineProperty(HomeController.prototype, "moviesToDownload", {
            get: function () {
                return this.$scope.moviesToDownload;
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });

        HomeController.prototype.markMovieAsDownloaded = function (movie) {
            movie.Downloaded = true;
        };

        HomeController.prototype.deleteMovieFromDownloadList = function (movie) {
            var _this = this;
            this.MovieService.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie).then(function () {
                debugger;
                _this.$scope.moviesToDownload = _.without(_this.$scope.moviesToDownload, movie);
            });
        };
        HomeController.$inject = [
            '$scope',
            '$location',
            'MovieService'
        ];
        return HomeController;
    })();
    movieApp.HomeController = HomeController;
})(movieApp || (movieApp = {}));

app.controller("HomeController", movieApp.HomeController);
//# sourceMappingURL=HomeController.js.map
```

As you can see, in the generated JS, the specific method uses _this. This looks right, right?

Could someone explain to me what happens and how to fix this?

EDIT:

I use this in combination with Angular:

```html
<body data-ng-app="movieApp" data-ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" data-ng-click="homeCtrl.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(m)" title="Verwijder uit lijst"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

EDIT II:
After trying all the suggestions and then setting back the original piece of code I've posted here, everything just works fine! I don't know how, but I guess it has something to do with Chrome / VS 2013. Anyway, thanks to those who have tried to help me out.

Comment: Probably the "deleteMovie..." function is bound to a button or other UI element. In this case this function is executed in the window context. To fix the issue, you should define the function body in the constructor of your controller: this.deleteMovieFromDownloadList = (movie: any) => {
            this.MovieService.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie).then(() => {
                debugger;
                this.$scope.moviesToDownload = _.without(this.$scope.moviesToDownload, movie);
            });
        }

Comment: I'm always move such functions in the constructor. I'm sure this is the simpliest way to fix the issue with "this" in TypeScript controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the "deleteMovie..." function is bound to a button or other UI element. In this case this function is executed in the window context. To fix the issue, you should define the function body in the constructor of your controller:

```
constructor(private $scope: IHomeControllerScope, private $location: ng.ILocationService, private MovieService) {
// other initialization code...

this.deleteMovieFromDownloadList = (movie: any) => {
    this.MovieService.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(movie).then(() => {
        debugger;
        this.$scope.moviesToDownload = _.without(this.$scope.moviesToDownload, movie);
    });
  }
}
```

and declare appropriate function in your controller class:

```
deleteMovieFromDownloadList: (movie: any) => void;
```

Comment: you can declare function with lambda outside controller as well: `deleteMovieFromDownloadList = (movie: any) => {... }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the issue is in how `deleteMovieFromDownloadList` is being called. If you do something like this:

```
var myController = new HomeController();
someFramework.doSomethingWithCallback(myController.deleteMovieFromDownloadList);
```

...`someFramework` would end up calling the callback without it being bound to the expected context. If this is the case, you can fix it by doing this:

```
var boundCallback = myController.deleteMovieFromDownloadList.bind(myController);
someFramework.doSomethingWithCallback(boundCallback);
```

**Update:**

In reading through the Angular documents, it appears that what you put in the click handler isn't really JavaScript, but is interpreted by Angular. So maybe `homeCtrl.deleteMovieFromDownloadList(m)` is doing something like this essentially:

```
var fn = homeCtrl.deleteMovieFromDownloadList;
fn(m):
```

...which of course would not set `this` correctly.

With the controller being set, can't you just do this?

```
data-ng-click="deleteMovieFromDownloadList(m)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, I can't do that because that method is not on `$scope`. That is why I use the `ControllerAs` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has some strange behaviors when it comes to constructor functions. I made an example to show you how it works:

```
function myClass() {
    var me = this;
    this.property = 'test';
    this.windowObj = function() {
        windowObjTest();
    }

    var windowObjTest = function() {
        console.log(this); // this = window object
    }

    this.myself = function() {
        myselfTest();
    }

    var myselfTest = function() {
        console.log(me); // me = this object
    }
}

var myobj = new myClass();
myobj.windowObj();
myobj.myself();
```

`this.windowObj();` is a public function to call the private function `windowObjTest();`. Inside a private function, `this` is a reference to the window object instead of this instance (don't ask me, the dev was high or something...). To get the reference of your current object into private functions, you have to set a reference of your current object into your constructor function: `var me = this;`.

Try the example and take a look into the console. Two entries should appear:

```
- Window test.php //console.log(this);
- myClass { property="test", windowObj=function(), myself=function()} //console.log(me);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with this. As you can see in the generated JS code, it already does what you imply: `var _this = this;` and this is exactly the reason why I don't understand why it isn't working, because in the callback of that function it uses `_this`.

Comment: I'm not sure if _this = this is correct in this context. You have to set _this = this in the class constructor to use it instead of the private function `HomeController.prototype.deleteMovieFromDownloadList`. At this place, you overwrite _this with the window object.

Comment: I think it is correct, because in the debugger I can see that when `_this = this` is invoked, `this` refers to the correct object.